# Nativescript angular keep app playing in background

Tags: nativescript

[nativescript] How do I keep a native script - angular app running in the background in IOS. I have a button that opens the in-app browser and there I have a webpage that plays music, I'd like the music to carry on playing when the user leaves the application.

here is my component.ts

```
export class BrowseComponent implements OnInit {
    openLink = async () => {
        try {
          const url = ''

          if (await InAppBrowser.isAvailable()) {
            const result = await InAppBrowser.open(url, {
              // iOS Properties
              dismissButtonStyle: 'done',
              preferredBarTintColor: '#3e00be',
              preferredControlTintColor: 'white',
              readerMode: false,
              animated: true,
              modalPresentationStyle: 'fullScreen',
              modalTransitionStyle: 'crossDissolve',
              modalEnabled: true,
              enableBarCollapsing: false,
              // Android Properties
              showTitle: true,
              toolbarColor: '#3e00be',
              secondaryToolbarColor: 'white',
              enableUrlBarHiding: true,
              enableDefaultShare: true,
              forceCloseOnRedirection: false,
              // Specify full animation resource identifier(package:anim/name)
              // or only resource name(in case of animation bundled with app).
              animations: {
                startEnter: 'slide_in_right',
                startExit: 'slide_out_left',
                endEnter: 'slide_in_left',
                endExit: 'slide_out_right'
              },
              headers: {
                'my-custom-header': 'my custom header value'
              }
            })
            // alert({
            //   title: 'Response',
            //   message: JSON.stringify(result),
            //   okButtonText: 'Ok'
            // })
          }
          else {

            MyDelegate.prototype.applicationDidEnterBackground = function (application: UIApplication) {
              console.log('App is running in background');openUrl(url);
              AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategoryWithOptionsError(
                  AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord,
                  AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.DefaultToSpeaker
              );
          };

          }
        }
        catch(error) {
          // alert({
          //   title: 'Error',
          //   message: error.message,
          //   okButtonText: 'Ok'
          // })
        }
      }

}
```

Comment: Can you explain why you have the delegate code in else part? Trying to understand why you are using enter background override only when in-app browser is not available.

Comment: @Manoj Thanks for responding, The else has the "openUrl(url)" which opens the in-app browser.
My problem is in the in-app Browser when I play audio and press the home button on IOS it stops and I've tried everything but it fails to keep the audio playing in the background

Comment: I'm unsure you could do this with WebView / in-app browser. Did you try nativescript audio plugin?

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. I will update if I figure it out. Thank you!